# Php filter how to replace a bit of code with something else?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys I want to learn to use php filters in wp enviroment to perform this: filter on

```
<?php do_action( 'glow_credits' ); ?>
```

to remove this credits and add just a copyright message... how can I do this?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content after
 */
?>

    </div><!-- #main .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="social-menu">
            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social', 'container' => 'false', 'menu_class' => 'menu-social' ));
            } ?>
        </div><!-- .social-menu -->
        <div class="site-info">
            <?php do_action( 'glow_credits' ); ?>
            <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'A Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'glow' ); ?>" rel="generator"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'glow' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>.
            <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'glow' ), 'Snaps', '<a href="http://glow.com/" rel="designer">glow</a>' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon .site-footer -->
</div><!-- #page .hfeed .site -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I know how to do this:

```
function test_new_action() {
  echo 'Howdy';
}
add_action('glow_credits','test_new_action');
```

but doesnt replace...

Comment: You can have multiple functions hook into an action. You will need to remove the original one that has the credit for it to work. Search your themes file for glow_credits and then you can find the associated function. You can also comment out the add_action function that is calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unhook the existing function using remove_filter() - you just need to find out the name of the function that is displaying the credits.

EG: If the function is called `display_credits` then you could use this in your function before hooking your own:

```
remove_filter( 'glow_credits', 'display_credits' );
```